# Disable Button for good

Tags: reactjs

Can I disable a Button in react when the *login user* is a member?
When I used the *disabled* attribute, it can be deleted from developer tools and the button is active again.

Please help me

I want the button to stay disabled when the *login user* is a member. Even after deleting the *disabled* attribute from developer tools, it shall still be inactive.

Comment: Yes you can and i provide you a demo using **React** and **Mutation Observer** and **State** but please read notice at the end of the post ,

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe this is the good solution. please check it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `disabled` prop to disable the button, but this will not prevent the user from removing the `disabled` attribute in the dev tools and enabling the button again. To avoid this, you should also use the disabled value to conditionally handle the click event listener from the button.

For example:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setDisabled((disabled) => !disabled)}>
        disable button
      </button>
      <button disabled={disabled} onClick={disabled ? null : handleClick}>
        click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This way, even if the user removes the `disabled` attribute, the button will not have any click handler attached to it.

---

## UPDATED ANSWER

Alternatively, you can set `pointer-events` style to `none`.

For example:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setDisabled((disabled) => !disabled)}>
        disable button
      </button>
      <button
        disabled={disabled}
        style={disabled ? { pointerEvents: "none" } : {}}
        onClick={console.log}
      >
        click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This way, you can stop the button from being clicked even if the user removes the style and the disabled property in the dev tools.

You can see the whole example here: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-mountain-nrw727?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable a button in React based on whether the login user is a member and prevent users from enabling it via developer tools, you need to handle the button's disabled state in a more secure way. One way to achieve this is by managing the button's disabled state within your component's state or using Redux.

Here's an example of how you can implement this:

- Assuming you have some state that indicates whether the login user is
  a member or not. For demonstration purposes, I'll use a boolean
  variable called `isMember` to represent this state.
- Initialize the button's disabled state based on the `isMember` value.
- Use React's lifecycle methods or React hooks (e.g., `useEffect`) to
  monitor changes to the `isMember` value and update the button's
  disabled state accordingly.
- When the button is clicked, perform the desired action only if it's
  not disabled.

Answer (score -3):

**Disabled button Forever**

you can **disabled the element** and **remove the click event listener** for the button like this when they **enabling** it via dev tools or they try to **change the state** the button dont work because **it point to a fake function** and finally you can add an **Mutation Observer** to make the **button Disabled for Forever**

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const elementRef = useRef();

  const [isDisabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (!isDisabled) {
      console.log("i am the orginal click handler");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    elementRef.current.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
  }, []);

  const handleDisabled = () => {
    if (!isDisabled) {
      setDisabled(true);
      elementRef.current.disabled = true;
      delete elementRef.current.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
      elementRef.current.onclick = () =>
        console.log("i am the fake click handler");

      var config = {
        attributes: true,
        childList: true,
        characterData: true
      };

      // Observer to block the element to be enabled from dev tools.
      var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach((record) => {
          // In each iteration an individual mutation can be accessed.

          // In this case if the type of mutation is of attribute run the following block.
          // A mutation could have several types.
          if (record.type === "attributes") {
            const changedAttrName = record.attributeName;

            if (changedAttrName === "disabled") {
              observer.disconnect(); // turn observer off;

              record.target.setAttribute("disabled", true);
              observer.observe(elementRef.current, config); // turn back on
            }
          }
        });
      });

      observer.observe(elementRef.current, config);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleDisabled}>disable button</button>
      <button ref={elementRef}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

also you can create a **custom hook** to disabled an element using his reference with mutation observer

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";
export function useForceDisabled(elementRef) {
  const [isObserving, setObserving] = useState(false);
  var config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true
  };

  // Observer to block the element to be enabled from dev tools.
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach((record) => {
      // In each iteration an individual mutation can be accessed.

      // In this case if the type of mutation is of attribute run the following block.
      // A mutation could have several types.
      if (record.type === "attributes") {
        const changedAttrName = record.attributeName;

        if (changedAttrName === "disabled") {
          observer.disconnect(); // turn observer off;
          record.target.setAttribute("disabled", true);
          observer.observe(elementRef.current, config); // turn back on
        }
      }
    });
  });

  const observe = useCallback(() => {
    if (!isObserving) {
      observer.observe(elementRef.current, config);
      setObserving(true);
    }
  }, []);

  const disconnect = useCallback(() => {
    if (isObserving) {
      observer.disconnect();

      setObserving(false);
    }
  }, []);

  return [observe, disconnect];
}
```

usage

```
  const [observe, disconnect] = useForceDisabled(elementRef);
  // call observe in function where you want to disabled the element
  observe();
```

**THE MOST IMPORTANT** : DISABLED A BUTTON AT **CLIENT SIDE** IS NOT SUFFISANT TO PROTECT YOUR APP **BE SUR AND BE SUR AT SERVER SIDE TO HANDLE THE CASE IF THEY ENABLED THE BUTTON USING ANY METHODS AND THEY TRY TO SEND DATA, YOU NEED TO BLOCK ALL UNWANTED REQUESTS AND ALWAYS CHECK IF THE USER CAN PERFOM AN ACTION**

you can try the code at https://codedamn.com/online-compiler/reactjs by copy paste